# Running Solr on VPS problems

Tags: java, php, linux

I have a VPS with Ubuntu OS.

I run solr om my local machine (windows xp laptop) just fine.

I have configured Jetty, and Solr just the same way as on my computer, but on the server.

I have also downloaded the JRE and installed it on the server.

However, whenever I try to run the start.jar file, the PuTTY terminal shows a bunch of text but gets stuck. I could pase the text here but it is very long, so unless somebody wants to see it I wont.

Also, I cant view the solr admin page at all.

Does anybody have experience in this kind of problem?

Maybe java isn't correctly installed? It is a VPS so maybe installation is different.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

These are the last lines from the terminal, in other words, this is where it stops every time:

```
INFO: [] webapp=null path=null params={event=firstSearcher&q=static+firstSearcher+warming+query+from+solrconfig.xml} hits=0 status=0 QTime=9
May 28, 2010 8:58:42 PM org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener newSearcher
INFO: QuerySenderListener done.
May 28, 2010 8:58:42 PM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent$SpellCheckerListener newSearcher
INFO: Loading spell index for spellchecker: default
May 28, 2010 8:58:42 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore registerSearcher
INFO: [] Registered new searcher Searcher@63a721 main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you checked to see if a firewall is running?  also, use netstat to see if there is a listener on port 8080 or whatever you have jetty assigned to.

Comment: I have disabled the firewall completely for this. No luck! jetty is on 8983, but nothing happens when trying to connect to that, just loads for a long time. Havent tried netstat, do you have the command for it to test if there is a listener?

Comment: Never mind, just checked. No listeners on that port... Although you should know that I installed jetty just by copy/pasting it from my HD to the server...